# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Bridge.local.pid)

Tags: mysql, linux, homebrew

I was not able to run mysql so i deleted it and reinstalled it using home brew .Now when i run the  mysql.server start command i get the following error

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Bridge.local.pid).
```

Here are the contents of my my.conf file in usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf where homebrew has installed mysql

```
# Use default setting for mysqld processes
!include default_mysqld.cnf
!include default_client.cnf

[mysqld.1]

# Run the master.sh script before starting this process
#!run-master-sh

log-bin=                 master-bin

# Run tests with the performance schema instrumentation
loose-enable-performance-schema

[mysqlbinlog]
disable-force-if-open

[ENV]
MASTER_MYPORT=           @mysqld.1.port
MASTER_MYSOCK=           @mysqld.1.socket
~
```

Comment: I guess you should tail /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: what do you mean by tailing l /var/log/mysql/error.log ?

Comment: I mean read the error.log.

Comment: I dont have a error log file at  this path and i try finding it in other places but cant find an error log file for mysql

Comment: Does that '. pid'  file exist? If yes (probably from a failed previous execution attempt) I 'd try renaming / deleting it.

Comment: may be mysqld can't start at all? try to ldd it?

Comment: @DanCornilescu i killed the pid using command sudo kill {pid number} but i still get the same error

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov Here is the outout from ldd equivalent command  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59.0.0)
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

Comment: yes, likely because the killed process left behind its pidfile (typically used to prevent multiple instances of the process running at the same time and/o to ensure the process leaves the db in a good state).  Just find and delete that pidfile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mysql does not have permission to the folder where the pid file is located in.

Solution working for my case:

1. Check your error log at /usr/local/var/mysql/Bridge.local.err
2. If there is something like this in the log: ...[Note] Unable to delete pid file: Permission denied..., which means mysql does not have the permission to 
   your mysql folder
3. Use the following command in terminal to grant the permission: sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/